# Eclipse IDE color theme does not work

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

Downloaded `Eclipse color theme` from Eclipse marketplace. Installed the plugin and restarted eclipse. When I apply the theme say "`Pastel`", it only applies to the text editor.

Why it does not apply entirely to the Eclipse IDE? All the other toolbars/panels are unaffected.

Version:

```
Eclipse IDE for Java Developers
Version: Mars.1 Release (4.5.1)
```

Platform:

```
Mac OSX Yosemite (10.10.5)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The plugin that you installed is designed to only apply to the text editor, but you can install additional plugins to change the theme of everything else while still using the pastel theme for text. If you want to stick with pastel then try downloading the moonrise theme from the marketplace.